# Good tutorials for routing a document in Sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, infopath

I would like to know if there are good tutorials for Microsoft Sharepoint.  Specifically solutions that involves routing documents for approval.  Use of Microsoft Infopath for form making and Microsoft SQL Server for the database is needed.  What I meant by good is that the quality that they possess is similar to the video tutorials of asp.net learn section.  Any help in this matter will be great.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a great video on the workflow part of your question.  He has other video's on InfoPath, etc but I haven't had time to watch them yet.

http://sheltonblog.com/archive/2007/11/21/how-to-video-building-a-basic-approval-workflow-with-sharepoint.aspx